# Using Generics in an IEqualityComparer in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a C# class defined like this:

```
public class Group<T> : ICloneable where T : CustomGroup
{
  ...
}
```

When I had originally implemented this, it was without generics. However, due to some new requirements, I've had to utilize generics on this class. Now, this class had an `IEqualityComparer`. It worked in it's pre-generics implementation. However, now, I'm not sure how to to define the class and method signatures.

```
public class GroupComparer : IEqualityComparer<Group>
{
  public bool Equals(Group a, Group b)
  {
    return (a.Id == b.Id);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Group obj)
  {
    return obj.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

This no longer compiles saying "Using the generic type Group requires 1 type arguments". However, I'm not sure how to update the class and method signatures to support `Group<T>` where T has to be a `CustomGroup`.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Why not iimplement `IEqualityComparer<Group<T>>` and make your comparer-class also generic?

Answer (score 2):

Make your comparer-class generic as well:

```
public class GroupComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Group<T>> where T : CustomGroup
{
  public bool Equals(Group<T> a, Group b<T>)
  {
    return (a.Id == b.Id);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Group<T> obj)
  {
    return obj.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the additional type constraint where T has to be a `CustomGroup` though?

Comment: You add that constraint onto the comparer class also.   The first line looks like `public class GroupComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Group<T>> where T : CustomGroup`